# How to move local server to live server in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to upload my local project into live server. 
i aslo changeall the .env related changes. but still it will not working.
So,what kind of changes need for live.

Comment: It would be best if you could update the question with details of the error message you're getting or a description of exactly how it is "not working" as it will enable people to provide more specific and relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following step you have must followed to move local to live server in Laravel.

1. Move all public folder data into root directory
2. In index.php change path to 
   require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';   to   require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

   AND

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';  to  $app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

   and set file permission to 744
3. Change parameter in .env file.

Comment: It should not be necessary to edit index.php or .htaccess. A properly configured .env file and virtual host is all that is needed to get Laravel working on production.

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution. it works.

1. laravel public folder move to public_html folder on server.
2. whole laravel project set outside public_html.
3. edit index.php that is in public folder in public_html (two line):

---

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

To:

```
require '../your_addrs/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app=require_once '../your_addrs/bootstrap/app.php';
```

find autoload.php and app.php and set your address server to two above line.